# How to make tracks for editing using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, video-editing

I'am writing a video editor and I need to add tracks in it. These things should support next actions (using mouse):

- 1)Borders positions changing( you can cut video/audio with it)
- 2)Track position changing relative to global timeline.

As you see these tracks are something like Adobe Premiere and Sony Vegas tracks but much simpler. My question is how to get this functionality using WPF. Which WPF controls can help me? I tried to use sliders but I failed.

Comment: There is no control that allows you to do this out of the box, but I've seen people do similar things using `Slider`. Check this: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx (though you'll need three Sliders, not only two)

Comment: http://mahapps.com/controls/range-slider.html